# Convert $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\cos(n)$ to definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

I search a lot, but I haven't found anything yet. How to convert this sum to a definite integral? Thank you for help.

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\cos(n)$$

Comment: Use Euler–Maclaurin formula 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What makes you think that there should be a way of converting this sum to a definite integral?

Comment: Do I get that right, **any** definite integral with the same value will do? In that case, I'd propose $\displaystyle\int^1_0\frac{\cos1-x}{1-2x\cos1+x^2}\,dx$.

Comment: @mwomath, the resulted series will be even more complicated than the original one for $f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{x}$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\cos (n)}{n}=\Re\left(\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^i}{-e^i+e^x} \, dx\right)$$

1)$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\cos (n)}{n}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \cos (n) \int_0^{\infty } \exp (-x n) \, dx=\int_0^{\infty } \left(\sum
   _{n=1}^{\infty } \cos (n) \exp (-x n)\right) \, dx=\int_0^{\infty } \Re\left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \exp (i n) \exp (-x n)\right) \,
   dx=\Re\left(\int_0^{\infty } \left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } e^{-n (-i+x)}\right) \, dx\right)=\Re\left(\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^i}{-e^i+e^x}
   \, dx\right)=\Re\left(-\log \left(1-e^i\right)\right)=-\frac{1}{2} \log (2-2 \cos (1))=\log \left(\frac{1}{2} \csc
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$